# Firebase Authentication + Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I've deployed a Cloud Function behind an API Gateway and configured Firebase Authentication, this all seems to work well.

Now I need to remove AllUsers so only authenticated users can call the function. I've setup an email based user in Firebase and generated a token for the user and it's accepted by the API Gateway but I get a 403 Forbidden because the user is not allowed to invoke the function.

How can I add an email based user as an account which can invoke the function, can't seem to see this in any documentation?

Comment: Seems its not possible and needs to be done in the Cloud Function using the Firebase Admin API: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the API gateway level, and more generally GCP IAM,  you can only allow/restrict access based on Google accounts that are collaborators on the project. There is unfortunately no way to filter on Firebase Authentication users at this level.

So you will have to do the authorization check inside the Cloud Functions code itself. In your comment you've already identified an approach to verify the ID token yourself which is also shown in this [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js), but if you implement your code as a [callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), that provides built-in decoding of the token into a [`context.auth` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function).